# Enable editing on UITextField using UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a view with two text fields and two segmented controls. I want each text field to become editable when its corresponding segmented control is selected.

Here is the approach I'm using:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if (textField == _textField) {
    if (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ||
        _segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 ||
        _segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 ||
        _segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 3) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
    if (textField == _textFieldTwo) {
        if (_segmentedControlTwo.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ||
            _segmentedControlTwo.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    }

}
```

}

This works for the first segmented control and textfield, but the second text field remains editable regardless of the condition of the second segmented control.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: check whether the delegate has been set for textFieldTwo and _segmentControlTwo outlets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IFs are not nested correctly.

```
if (textField == _One){
  if( 0<= selectedIndex < 4) {
      //do something
  } else {
      return no;
  } 
  if (textField == _Two){
      // other stuff
  }
}
```

Can you see that the if(textFieldTwo) is *inside* the if(textFieldOne) ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a simple logic error to me.  Your:

```
if (textField == _textFieldTwo) {
```

should really be an `else if` on the first `if`.

Simply change it to:

```
} else if (textField == _textFieldTwo) {
```

and it should start working.

Comment: Hey aethe, thanks for the response. Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: I've tried to achieve the same outcome using the setEnabled and userInteractionEnabled properties of the text field as follows:       `-(void)enableDisableEditing {
    if (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == -1) {
        _textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    } else if (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 || _segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 || _segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        _textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
}`                                                                  but that hasn't worked either.